# Why velocity across the actuator disc is constant: Assumption or a result of continuity equation?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, momentum, conservation-laws, velocity, flow

In the context of [actuator disc](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Momentum_theory) theory, we can find the following quote from that article:

[image]

> The rotor is modeled as an infinitely thin disc, inducing a constant velocity along the axis of rotation.

- I am confused: Is it possible to make small control volume (with infinitesimal width) around the actutor disc so we can apply the continuity equation:

$$
\rho^-\cdot A^- \cdot V^- = \rho^+ \cdot A^+ \cdot V^+
$$

Where $(X^-)$ denotes variable just before the actutor disc, and $(X^+)$ variable just after the disc.

From the assumptions of the theory: $\rho^- = \rho^+ = \rho$ , and $A^- = A^+ = A$ we get:

$$
V^- = V^+ = V
$$

- Is it correct to proceed as above to prove that the velocity $V$ accross the actuator disc is constant? or I am violating some principles (thus the theory needs to assume a constant velocity accross the actuator disc in the first place)?

You help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is a result of the continuity equation, assuming that the density is constant across the actuator disk.

Comment: Could you please elaborate. Since we cannot apply the bernouli equation because of the jump in pressure (pressure jump across actuator disc = non-conservative-force = Bernouli equation is not applicable). I wonder if that prevents us from applying continuity as well.

Comment: It was not clear to me from your question that you had this doubt. I'm editing my answer. You should edit your question to explicitly write your doubt about Bernoulli's thm